# no spaces betwen two tr tags

Tags: html

I cannot seem to reduce the space between two TR tags. I have the following code. I don't want any space between two tr tags.

```
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-        color:#d7d6d4" > 
    <tr   > 
    <td align="center" style="height:0px; line-height:0px; background:#932a28;         border:0; border-bottom:0"> 
              <asp:Image ID="newLogo" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/images/middle_logo_top.jpg"/> 

    </td> 

</tr> 

<tr > 
    <td  align="center" style="height:10px;  background:#e5e0dd"> 
         <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/middle_logo_btm.jpg"/> 


    </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: tables are for tabular data, not for layouting.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you showed us. Show us a full HTML document as served to browsers (no ASP code) that demonstrates the issue. (Your question might still get closed, because people don’t like layout tables.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: That's not a valid close reason.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, I didn’t say it was a valid close reason, I just warned; there were “answers” that just said “don’t use tables.” But lack of clarifications to the question was a valid cause, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you are asking - to remove the space in your markup or to remove the space in the browsers presentation of the markup ?

If the latter you are best off learning some css, then you can remove inline styling, stop using tables for layouts and attach **display:block** and other helpers to objects to get a grip of your  presentation job ...

```
<style type="text/css">

   div , div img { display:block }
   .fl { float:left; }

</style>

<div class="fl"><img src="image1.jpg alt=""/></div>
<div class="fl"><img src="image2.jpg alt=""/></div>
```

Does the same as your table and probally sorts the space problems out

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use CSS for layout and stop using tables.

Look at this : http://sixrevisions.com/web-standards/20-html-best-practices-you-should-follow/